# apache: Forbidden You don't have permission to access, even folder has permissions

Tags: apache

I get `Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server`.

Here is config from apache

```
<VirtualHost paper.local:80>
                     ServerName paper.local
    DocumentRoot "/home/html/paper.local/www"
                 <Directory "/home/html/paper.local/www">
                            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride  All
        Order  allow,deny
        Allow  from all
                    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is folder permissions. Same for all files and subfolders. Apache runs under www-data user.

```
/home/html$ ls -lah
drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data alex 4,0K jun 31 19:55 paper.local
```

What else is need to change in order make it works?

Comment: oh dear, I spent all day on this issue, and when I posted the question here, got an idea, checked the main config and found what else need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is need to change to /home/html too.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```